# Is it legal in the US for a student to download a copy of a textbook, to study?

Tags: united-states, copyright, books, online-resource, legal-issues

(this is coming out of a comment thread regarding [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/52678/what-is-the-point-of-a-lecture-when-you-have-a-textbook/52690#52690).)

The USA has a Fair Use legal provision restricting its copyright law:

> 17 U.S.C. § 107
>
> Notwithstanding the provisions of sections 17 U.S.C. §
>   106 and 17 U.S.C. § 106A, the fair use of a copyrighted work,
>   including such use by reproduction in copies or phonorecords or by any
>   other means specified by that section, for purposes such as criticism,
>   comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for
>   classroom use), **scholarship**, or research, is not an infringement of
>   copyright. In determining whether the use made of a work in any
>   particular case is a fair use the factors to be considered shall
>   include:
>
> 1. the purpose and character of the use, including whether such use is of a commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;
> 2. the nature of the copyrighted work;
> 3. the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole;
> 4. and the effect of the use upon the potential market for or value of the copyrighted work.
>
> The fact that a work is unpublished shall not itself bar a finding of fair use if such finding is made upon consideration of all the above factors.

Obviously there might be other relevant statutes and legal precedents, but  still,

1. Is it legal, considering the above, for a university/college student to download a copy of a textbook (say, in a course s/he is taking), for studying the course material?
2. Same question, for a student not enrolled in a class for which the downloaded book is a textbook?
3. Same question, for self-study outside of Academia?

Notes:

- "Legal" in two senses: First, the sense of very small chance of being convicted of a criminal act or obligated to pay money; second, the sense of there being a solid argument for the legality of this act which is likely to hold up if you appeal and appeal and maybe get to the supreme court.
- Assume it's been established that the downloader did not publish the copy elsewhere, did not cite from it extensively, etc. etc.
- I'm not asking whether it's *moral* or *ethical* to download textbooks, only about the legality. I believe it *is* moral and ethical, but that discussion is not what this question is about; please don't start it.

Comment: [This link](http://guides.nyu.edu/c.php?g=276684&p=1848033) has several examples of common copyright-related scenarios in universities and explains how to evaluate whether they are fair use or not.

Comment: I think it's wrong to ignore ethics. Back in my undergrad days, I led a committee within my large state university's student government to reform the way our campus bookstore approached their purchases. We explored ideas like increasing the effort our bookstore made in negotiating prices and the idea of acquiring books from alternate sources (among other ideas, re-importing international editions). The brick wall we hit when dealing with what I consider the too-friendly relationship between publishers and the monopolistic campus bookstore has convinced me this is an issue of ethics.

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "legal". Law is the complex product of statutes, regulations, precedent, and subjective feeling of the case-deciders. If something is technically disallowed by statute, the statute could be an effective nullity if it is never enforced. I believe that no penalty has even been imposed on a student in the context you describe, so it is in that sense "legal". Also note that "fair use" is a defense, meaning you have to prove it if you are brought up on charges.

Comment: @user6726: *Also note that "fair use" is a defense, meaning you have to prove it if you are brought up on charges.* In the US, this type of copying is not even potentially a criminal offense. It's a civil matter. You risk getting sued, not criminally charged.

Comment: @TomDworzanski: I'm not ignoring ethics, I'm just not having that argument on this site. See my edit. As for the campus bookstore - your problem is the university body which lets them operate as they do... I would try to get the student union and academic staff union(s) to take collective action to change this situation.

Comment: The first sense of 'legal' is not a sense of the term 'legal' as used in standard English at all. That the chances of Jones getting caught for killing Davies in a particularly obscure way are vanishing small does not make Jones doing so 'legal' in *any* sense of the term. As Alice points out to Humpty Dumpty, the question is whether *you* can make a word mean so many things....

Comment: As I understand it, 'fair use' governs the *use* of copyrighted material. It is not about that material's *acquisition*. If I purchase an ebook, I might or might not be able to defend as 'fair use' sharing part or all of book with you for a certain purpose. I cannot, as I understand it, use it to defend my acquisition of the ebook if that's the issue which lands me in court.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorry, I didn't mean to direct my comments at you so much as I was just making a more general comment. I understand and respect the purpose of your question.

Comment: When asking questions about what is "legal", appeal to common usage is the last thing you should rely on. 'It would be a narrow conception of jurisprudence to confine the notion of "laws" to what is found written on the statute books, and to disregard the gloss which life has written upon it' (310 U.S. 362). It is fundamentally unknowable whether such downloading is prohibited by the *totality* of the law, though reading only the statutory part would say that it is.

Comment: Just curious, setting aside the poorly named stipends you apply for that are common called "scholarships" (because stipend isn't very motivating to high schoolers) do you consider all education to be scholarship? I highly suspect the scholarship they refer to is not just any and all educational purposes, but rather the advancement of a field i.e. research.

Comment: @cfr If acquisition of the content involves reproducing it (as downloading material to your computer necessarily does) then it may be governed by fair use. It's actually explicit in [copyright law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use#Fair_use_under_United_States_law): "...the fair use of a copyrighted work, including such use by reproduction..." The closest analogy is making photocopies of a library book for yourself, also a means of "acquiring" content involving reproduction; that, too, may be defensible under fair use in some circumstances.

Comment: Perhaps this would be a suitable question for the [Law Stack Exchange](http://law.stackexchange.com)? As far as I know, not many of us here study law, and this certainly seems like a legal question more than an academic one.

Comment: @chipbuster: I didn't realize there was a Law SX ... it might have been a valid question there, but I think it's also valid here - academia involves both law, sociology, anthropology, economics, philosophy, history...

Comment: @ff524 The cases are not analogous. In the case of the library book, you are starting with a legally acquired copy: the library buys a copy of the book (ebook, paper book, whatever). It then lends that copy to you, which is also legal. But the library is not relying on the defence of 'fair use'.

Comment: @cfr the issue (the copyright infringement that could potentially be defended with fair use) is the copy *you* make, the source you are copying from is not strictly relevant to this direct copyright infringement. (In fact, my university library used to have signs posted near the copy machines informing students that photocopying too much of a book is potentially copyright infringement.)

Comment: @ff524 That is exactly my point. Does US law not make that distinction?

Comment: @cfr I'm not aware of *any* jurisdiction where an unauthorized copy of an authorized copy is treated differently in the law from an unauthorized copy of an unauthorized copy. Are you? (Do you have a specific example?)

Comment: @ff524 But the question is surely whether the download would be an authorised copy of an unathorised copy.

Comment: @cfr No. This question is about whether making an unauthorized copy (which is generally copyright infringement) can be excused with a fair use defense. As long as you don't have permission from the rights holder to make a copy, it's an unauthorized copy, whether you make a photocopy of a library book, or download it from a website, or go to a bookstore and take photos of every single page with your phone when nobody is looking...

Comment: @ff524 OK. Yes. Fair enough. I misspoke. The question is whether the an unauthorised copy of an unauthorised copy could be defended as fair use, given that the latter could not be. At least, that's how I understood it.

Comment: The purpose of the Fair Use doctrine, especially with respect to academia is to allow published works to be reviewed and discussed, while still protecting the copyright holders rights to charge for full and/or effective use.  In other words, a copyright holder cannot use their copyright to prevent public and/or scholarly review and criticism of their work (i.e., critics/reviewers can quote passages to support their points). At the same time, readers cannot use the doctrine to bypass paying for their copies when they are actually reading the whole thing (or a substantial portion).

Comment: @RBarryYoung: That's one/some of the purposes - research, commentary, criticism. There's also scholarship, mentioned separately.

Comment: @einpoklum I believe that scholarship refers to scholarly references and quotes (a form of review), and is not intended to mean "self-education by reading most of the work without paying for it". Note that scholarship and education are not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: 1. Scholarship is pretty much self-education by studying something. Studying the text of a book seems like scholarship to me - although I'm not a native speaker of English, so you may be right. Still, research is mentioned separately. 2. Indeed, scholarship and education are not the same thing - education is something you (typically) apply to other people.

Comment: If your reasoning is correct it would apply to other copyrighted material other than textbook as well,  if it is used for studying. Consider a student of cinematography. He should be allowed to download and freely watch all movies since when's watching then he's studying... What do you think would happen in this other instance if some Hollywood company sued you?

Comment: @Bakuriu: You're right, but how many people are students of cinematography? Now, anyone could claim he was downloading a copy of a work for self-study, but that's why I separated the 3 cases in my question. If I were to ask it about a film and film students, it seems to me like a student taking a class on Truffaut could better make a fair use argument about downloading a copy of Jules and Jim.

Comment: To point 2 of Fair Use, the copyright page of any textbook will either say "All Rights Reserved," or will have something to the effect of this "All rights reserved. No part of this book covered by the copyright herein may be reproduced or used in any format in any form or by any means—graphic, electronic, or mechanical, including photocopying, recording, taping, or information storage and retrieval systems—without permission of the publisher." So in that respect the nature of the copyright is that the copyright holder, unless expressly granted otherwise, expects that every copy be paid for.

Comment: The fair use doctrine comes more out of a desire to protect US Constitutional First Amendment rights without the risk of suppression of criticism by the threat of a law suit. The intention has never been to allow for use not authorized by the copyright holder. Fair use also can be applied to free expression in the production of derivative works, so even though Campbell's soup holds a copyright on its labels, Andy Warhol's work was substantively different enough from the original to be considered fairly used.

Comment: Publishers will often chose to provide professors with free instructor copies as an incentive for them to evaluate and adopt the book for their course, which as the copyright holder is their choice to do, but they have no intention to allow that professor to then copy that book and distribute to their class. Even if the professor were to purchase a PDF of the book, they would not have license to then post that PDF to their course resources site for students to use. There expectation is that the book will be purchase, at least by one generation of students.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Short answer: **Nope**.

Long answer: **It's complicated.**

The proportion of the work copied can actually be the whole of the work (i.e. 100%), if the *other* parts of the fair use test provide a strong enough justification:

> The extent of permissible copying
> varies with the purpose and character of the use. Taking more of the copyrighted work
> than is necessary to accomplish the fair user’s salutary purpose will weigh against fair
> use. **In some cases, the fact that the entire work** — for example, an image — **was needed to
> accomplish the fair use purpose has led the court to hold that the third factor was neutral,
> favoring neither the copyright holder nor the putative fair user**.

[Copyright and Fair Use: A Guide for the Harvard Community](http://ogc.harvard.edu/files/ogc/files/copyright_and_fair_use_a_guide_for_the_harvard_community_0.pdf), Harvard University Office of the General Counsel, Last Updated
November 23, 2009

Unfortunately, the courts haven't consistently viewed educational use as 'fair use' *per se*:

> On its face, the text of the statute seems to favor educational uses of works as fair uses.  It first lists a variety of educational purposes such as criticism, comment, teaching, scholarship, and research as prototypical fair uses.  It then identifies the use of content for “nonprofit educational purposes” as an explicit consideration in the first of the four enumerated factors for consideration in a fair use analysis.
>
> In practice, however, **courts have not consistently found that educational uses qualify as fair uses**.  Because the doctrine is applied on a case-by-case basis and resists reduction to a per-se rule, it provides limited assurance to scholars and teachers seeking bright-line guidance.  ... even scholars well-read in precedent may be hard-pressed to find consistent analyses, across different federal courts, of educational copying and other scholarly uses.

[Digital Learning Legal Background Paper:
Fair Use and Educational Uses of Content](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc), Ashley Aull for the Berkman Center for Internet and Society at Harvard Law School

So you need to look at how the other three parts of the test pertain in the particular case at issue.

Unfortunately, in regard to the first factor:

> In determining whether a use is “commercial,” courts generally find that the “distinction is not whether the sole motive of the use is monetary gain but **whether the user stands to profit from exploitation of the copyrighted material without paying the customary price**.” Thus, despite the fact the statutory text contrasts commercial with nonprofit educational purposes, courts may exclude schools and universities from the protection of the fair use doctrine if they “benefit” from such uses.

Harper & Row Publishers, Inc. v. Nation Enterprises, 471 U.S. 539 (1984) as cited in [Aull](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc)

And in regard to the fourth factor:

> the Court has held that “a challenge [of a use]…requires proof either that the particular use is harmful, or that **if it should become widespread, it would adversely affect the potential market** for the copyrighted work.”

Sony Corp. of America v. Universal City Studios Inc., 464 U.S. 417 (1984) as cited in [Aull](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc).

We should therefore take account of a couple of facts that pertain in our hypothetical situation:

- the student benefits from their use of the material,
- if all students were to copy the material without paying for it then the market for the material would be destroyed, which would hurt the incentive system for the production of new works,

and those facts seem to me to imply that copying (or downloading a copy of) an entire textbook, where the alternative is paying to purchase the textbook, would *usually not* be 'fair use' under US law.

**But** exceptions to this are possible. If the *whole* work was *vital* for scholarship but *not* commercially available then a pretty strong argument for 100% copying as fair use could be made. For the full picture read [Aull](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc).

---

**Update** in response to comments:

@einpoklum, thanks for your insightful comments. I thought they deserved proper discussion, so I'm answering them here, where I've got more space to address them.

> *It seems that the complicated situation is more in the case of educational institutions using full cpies.*

You're correct that the case law (at least as far as I'm aware) that's specifically about textbooks concerns organisations (such as businesses and educational institutions) rather than individuals.

That's likely to be because it's not worth suing an individual for a very small loss. If the textbook only costs $20 - or even if it costs $100 - the publisher would lose money by suing the student, because the non-recoverable costs of the case (such as the time of the publisher's staff) would cost more than that. This is the reason why lawsuits in P2P filesharing cases tend to be filed against the uploader rather than the downloader.

> *But has there ever been a conviction, or a ruling in a civil suit, against a student who downloaded a copy of a textbook?*

Not that I'm aware of. The very small amount of damages that could be recovered would mean that this would be a loss-making lawsuit even if it were won, although it might have a certain deterrent effect.

"Can I get away with doing this without being sued?" (to which the answer is almost certainly '**Yup**') is of course a different question from "Is it legal?".

> *Also, any copier of any work stands to benefit from it somehow, otherwise they wouldn't make the copy; it seems you're interpreting that sentence too widely.*

It certainly is a very wide interpretation! Unfortunately this is the interpretation which the US courts seem to give it.

[Aull](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc) makes this point as well:

> of course, one might strain to find a situation in which educators would use content without benefiting from it somehow.

[Aull](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc), footnote 10, page 5.

> The Guidelines for Classroom Copying have received the most scholarly and judicial attention.  While recognizing that some photocopying of copyrighted material for classroom distribution is fair use, the Guidelines require that such copying, in addition to having clear copyright notice on each copy, fall within three specifically described limits: “brevity,” “spontaneity,” and “cumulative effect.”  The American Association of University Professors and Association of American Law Schools vigorously opposed these Guidelines, stressing that they “**restrict the doctrine of fair use so substantially as to make it almost useless for classroom teaching purposes**.”  Meanwhile, in a series of strategic lawsuits filed soon after the passage of the 1976 Act, publishing interests succeeded in persuading some courts to view those Guidelines as an authoritative gauge of fair use.

[Aull](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc), p.7

> *Also, your claim about market destruction is simply invalid - just like with the music industry, people continue to buy music, concert tickets etc. despite having downloaded copies off of the Internet.*

This is a view with which I have much sympathy. Unfortunately the same cannot be said for the US courts.

An example from the Napster case:

> 4. Effect of Use on Market ...
>
> [31] Addressing this factor, the district court concluded that **Napster harms the market in “at least” two ways**: it reduces audio CD sales among college students and it “raises barriers to plaintiffs’ entry into the market for the digital downloading of music.” Napster, 114 F. Supp. 2d at 913. The district court relied on evidence plaintiffs submitted to show that Napster use harms the market for their copyrighted musical compositions and sound recordings. In a separate memorandum and order regarding the parties’ objections to the expert reports, the district court examined each report, finding some more appropriate and probative than others. A&M Records, Inc. v. Napster, Inc., Nos. 99-5183 & 00-0074, 2000 WL 1170106 (N.D. Cal. August 10, 2000). Notably, plaintiffs’ expert, Dr. E. Deborah Jay, conducted a survey (the “Jay Report”) using a random sample of college and university students to track their reasons for using Napster and the impact Napster had on their music purchases. Id. at *2. The court recognized that the Jay Report focused on just one segment of the Napster user population and found “**evidence of lost sales attributable to college use to be probative of irreparable harm for purposes of the preliminary injunction motion**.” Id. at *3.
>
> [32] Plaintiffs also offered a study conducted by Michael Fine, Chief Executive Officer of Soundscan, (the “Fine Report”) to determine the effect of online sharing of MP3 files in order to show irreparable harm. **Fine found that online file sharing had resulted in a loss of “album” sales within college markets.** After reviewing defendant’s objections to the Fine Report and expressing some concerns regarding the methodology and findings, the district court refused to exclude the Fine Report insofar as plaintiffs offered it to show irreparable harm. Id. at *6.
>
> [33] Plaintiffs’ expert Dr. David J. Teece studied several issues (“Teece Report”), including whether plaintiffs had suffered or were likely to suffer harm in their existing and planned businesses due to Napster use. Id. Napster objected that the report had not undergone peer review. The district court noted that such reports generally are not subject to such scrutiny and overruled defendant’s objections. Id.
>
> ...
>
> [36] We, therefore, conclude that **the district court made sound findings related to Napster’s deleterious effect on the present and future digital download market**. Moreover, lack of harm to an established market cannot deprive the copyright holder of the right to develop alternative markets for the works. See L.A. Times v. Free Republic, 54 U.S.P.Q.2d 1453, 1469-71 (C.D. Cal. 2000) (stating that online market for plaintiff newspapers’ articles was harmed because plaintiffs demonstrated that “[defendants] are attempting to exploit the market for viewing their articles online”); see also UMG Recordings, 92 F. Supp. 2d at 352 (“Any allegedly positive impact of defendant’s activities on plaintiffs’ prior market in no way frees defendant to usurp a further market that directly derives from reproduction of the plaintiffs’ copyrighted works.”). Here, similar to L.A. Times and UMG Recordings, the record supports the district court’s finding that the “record company plaintiffs have already expended considerable funds and effort to commence Internet sales and licensing for digital downloads.” 114 F. Supp. 2d at 915. **Having digital downloads available for free on the Napster system necessarily harms the copyright holders’ attempts to charge for the same downloads**.
>
> [37] Judge Patel did not abuse her discretion in reaching the above fair use conclusions, nor were the findings of fact with respect to fair use considerations clearly erroneous.

[A&M RECORDS, Inc. v. NAPSTER, INC., 239 F.3d 1004 (9th Cir. 2001)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/copyright/cases/239_F3d_1004.htm)

> *I'm hearing speculative opinions on the prospective interpretation of the law.*

Yes, that's entirely correct. In the absence of an existing case which exactly replicates the hypothetical situation you're proposing, that's all that anyone can give you. If you want a probably-more-accurate speculative opinion then consult a lawyer, but it'll still just be their opinion.

That doesn't mean, though, that the law doesn't apply until there's been a case which covers exactly these circumstances.

> *In the mean time, it seems perhaps nobody has even been sued or tried criminally for doing this, and it is a widespread practice. So...*

So you'd probably not be sued. That's correct, but doesn't mean that the practise is necessarily legal.

A few notes:

- You should also be aware that many US universities have their own rules which are **more** restrictive than copyright law:

> more than 80 percent of American universities now adhere to internal policies derived from the Classroom Guidelines that university lobbying groups has rejected.  Some enforce even stricter guidelines, all but prohibiting reliance upon fair use.  At least one commentator has predicted that, in this environment, “**current trends…will eventually eliminate fair use for schools, colleges and universities**.”

[Aull](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/wg_home/uploads/817/Fair_use_legal_background.doc), p.8

- I encourage you to continue to campaign in favour of a more liberal definition of 'fair use'. [The EFF is an excellent place to start.](https://www.eff.org/issues/intellectual-property) Lawrence Lessig's book '[Free Culture](http://www.free-culture.cc/freeculture.pdf)' also makes for an interesting read on this topic.

Comment: It seems that the complicated situation is more in the case of educational institutions using full cpies. But has there ever been a conviction, or a ruling in a civil suit, against a student who downloaded a copy of a textbook?

Comment: Also, any copier of any work stands to benefit from it somehow, otherwise they wouldn't make the copy; it seems you're interpreting that sentence too widely. Also, your claim about market destruction is simply invalid - just like with the music industry, people continue to buy music, concert tickets etc. despite having downloaded copies off of the Internet.

Comment: Finally, based on your long answer, I would say the short answer is: "yup."

Comment: @einpoklum It seems to me you had an answer in mind when you asked the question.

Comment: @MattSamuel: 1. See my first note in the question , and 2. Yes, I did - reading the Fair Use description, to me it was pretty clear that the answer was "yes". I was kind of surprised anybody would claim differently.

Comment: @einpoklum AE's point on market destruction is perfectly valid. If **everyone** would illegaly download music the market would be destroyed. Copying of text books on a wide-spread scale would obviously mean a loss in profits for the publishers as those people would no longer (be forced to) buy the text. I'm not sure why you're still refusing to accept that the answer, in general, is a flat no. *Dura lex sed lex*.

Comment: @Lilienthal: Umm, I'm sorry to break this to you, but essentially everyone _is_ downloading music. At any rate, I was talking about an individual; and an individual can't be tried in place of "everyone" and based on what "everyone" _might_ do. I don't find this dura lex, harsh law, that you speak of. I'm hearing speculative opinions on the prospective interpretation of the law. In the mean time, it seems perhaps nobody has even been sued or tried criminally for doing this, and it is a widespread practice. So...

Comment: @einpoklum Given that the music industry generated a global revenue of [15 billion USD in 2013](http://www.billboard.com/biz/articles/news/global/5937645/ifpi-music-report-2014-global-recorded-music-revenues-fall-4), I guess not **everyone** is downloading music. And if you had bother to read AE's answer you would see that your second point is equally invalid: "if it should become widespread, it would adversely affect the potential market ". In other words, the court ruled that even if one individual's behaviour would not be hugely problematic, the change that his behaviour would spread *is*.

Comment: @Lilienthal: You're assuming people who buy music don't download it, and that's not true. Also, about the court ruling - let's have a link to that. But not a ruling regarding the _publication_ of copies or their _sale_, but about their _download_.

Comment: @einpoklum Instead of perverting the arguments made here, consider reading them. At this point I'm going to recommend that you put a lawyer on retainer or hire a yes man because I doubt you're going to get what you want on this site.

Comment: @einpoklum, I've added to my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: Since you cite so much case law: the ongoing case involving [Georgia State](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_University_Press_v._Patton) is highly relevant here. Specifically with respect to (4), the decision there was that the excerpts shared by instructors were considered to be fair use partly because they "do not substitute for the full books". Also with respect to (3) the lower court suggested very specific quantitative guidelines; although the use of specific quantitative rules was overturned on appeal.

Comment: @ff524 Very interesting!

Comment: 'Fair use' was understood in a way which made it virtually useless for instructional purposes even 10 years ago. Course readers in the US are typically combinations of materials from various sources e.g. a poem from a book, an article from a journal, a paper from a collection. Each item in such a reader typically has to have copyright clearance and publishers levy a charge for this. They also charge for some items placed on electronic reserve in libraries. (And all this is true even if the library owns copies of the material.) Only if you can claim that the use of material was unforeseeable...

Comment: ... can you typically get away with distributing copies of it for free. Note that I realise the question is about individual use, but the 'fair use' defence is supposed to be available there, too. (At least for non-profit educational institutions.) These policies are, of course, defensive in nature. They are, unfortunately, both shaped by, and shape, interpretations of the 'fair use' clause in US courts, which have tended - though not without exceptions - to interpret what is defensible rather restrictively. This is unfortunate morally, socially & educationally, but sets the US legal context.

Comment: @ff524: Just wanted to emphasize that your Georgia State reference regards the act of distribution to others (within the framework of an educational program which students pay for, or the government pays for). In that context I obviously agree there is well-established illegality of distributing copies of books. The context of my question is different.

Comment: @einpoklum The relevant points of the Georgia State case here are not 1, the nature of the use (e.g. distribution vs personal use), or 2. The parts I brought up are 4 and 3, which both relate to the idea of using a copyrighted work in its entirety (vs a small part of it).  (You seem determined to completely dismiss any relevant case law that isn't *exactly* the scenario you have in mind, but that's not how case law works. Courts use relevant parts of related but non-identical precedents to guide their decisions in new contexts that have not yet been decided in the courts.)

Comment: @ff524: But, again, it was found inappropriate to _distribute_ an entire work. From reading the text it seems to me that it was intended to be limited in scope. And, yes, my question was kind of specific..

Comment: "That's likely to be because it's not worth suing an individual for a very small loss. If the textbook only costs $20 - or even if it costs $100 - the publisher would lose money by suing the student, because the non-recoverable costs of the case (such as the time of the publisher's staff) would cost more than that." As publishers register their works with the US Copyright Office, then "Registered works may be eligible for statutory damages and attorney's fees in successful litigation." That means a court could decide to force an individual violator to pay the expenses of the publisher....

Comment: ... and while it isn't likely, and the courts may frown upon its docket being filled with a publisher bringing individual lawsuits against thousands of violators, you take on that risk if you download copyrighted work without license to do so. I fully support free access to information, but it is up to the creator of the work to decide to make that content freely available through Creative Commons licensing.

Comment: Where I actually have a problem is where work has been funded by public grants, such as NSF or NIH grants, and the work ends up getting published in Journals that have pay walls. The knowledge generated by those researchers was funded by the taxpayers and should be made available to the public that paid for it, and not be a source of profit for journals that place embargoes on the data's access and charge exorbitant amounts to access what should rightly be The People's knowledge. I do not see a textbook that was generated for the purpose of profit in the same light.

Comment: @AMR, agreed. Re costs, there's usually some that can't be recovered from the losing party. Eg I can claim for my lawyer's fees but probably not for my own time used in consulting the lawyer and dealing with the case - this is why I said "non-recoverable costs".

Answer (score 47):

In general, it is not considered fair use to download the entirety of a textbook, regardless of whether or not you're a student or enrolled in a class using the textbook. Fair use normally is considered to extend to making copies of small excerpts of larger works. For instance, you could copy a particularly relevant figure from a book, or a quote from a textbook or reader for use in a class discussion.

Comment: I was asking about the specific case of scholarship - and I think you're giving an overly general answer, or referring to use in teaching, which is something done for pay/tuition.

Comment: My point is that fair use never extends to downloading an entire textbook when you do not formally have the rights to do so. There is no exception for scholarship purposes.

Comment: @einpoklum see point #3: "the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole"

Comment: @einpoklum The third factor "the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole" is the major factor here. Regardless of the other 3 points, it is pretty obvious that downloading an **entire textbook** is not fair use. And the fourth factor "the effect of the use upon the potential market for or value of the copyrighted work" is also clearly a problem in this usage. If every student could download the book without paying for it, it would seriously affect the value of the work.

Comment: @MJeffryes at the same time, I haven't seen any books that can be downloaded chapter-by-chapter or similar, what's a few kb when only 1% will be used?

Comment: @user2813274 Even if it would be fair use to obtain a single book chapter, its unavailability online doesn't make downloading the whole thing fair use. It's possible that if you were sued for infringing and you argued that you only used a single chapter, the judgement would be in your favour. There's no way of knowing.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't think the answerer has misunderstood or generalised. Its a bit of wishful thinking on your part.  The scholor clause is obviously so that you can take excerpts from a full text you have legitimately and not for procuring the full text in the first place.

Comment: @user2813274. I believe the onus would be on you to prove that you only used 1% of the work if you did indeed download the entire book. You might be able to get away with it, but chances are, you won't.

Comment: "For instance, you could copy [X from Y]" -- ... which you *legally* obtained, right?

Comment: @MJeffryes: The opposite is clear. As a student, a scholar, you would obviously need to read the whole book. The "amount" consideration seems like it would regard, say, citation somewhere.

Comment: So, @aeismail, has there ever been a conviction, or a ruling in a lawsuit, according to your point?

Comment: @JamesRyan: How is that obvious? Have the courts specifically ruled according to that interpretation?

Comment: @einpoklum: I would imagine there has been, but copyright infringement suits don't normally make the news. However, you should see [this page from the Stanford Libraries](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/) that discusses fair use in greater detail. (Note copyright infringement is normally a civil, not criminal, matter).

Comment: @einpoklum I cannot find any conviction for pirating textbooks. However, I suspect this is not because the courts have ruled it legal so much as it is because nobody has tried to prosecute individual downloaders yet. The RIAA [abandoned the strategy of suing individual infringers in 2008](http://www.techhive.com/article/155769/riaa_p2p_lawsuits.html), and copyright cases over ebooks has only [recently started becoming heated](http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/0/988850e0-038c-11e5-a70f-00144feabdc0.html). Between these two factors, I don't think there's a precedent for fair use of pirated books.

Comment: @einpoklum individual countries often give advice on how to interpret these laws and yes there are civil cases brought all the time against people and organisations misuse. You are naively questioning something which is established and widely accepted, you have not found a sneaky loophole.

Comment: @JamesRyan: It is not naivete, it's a different cultural (and legal) background - in Israel it's completely legal. It seems incredibly bizarre that something like this would be illegal. As chipbuster suggests, though, it seems this is not actually established (= no court ruling) and not actually accepted (= hundreds of millions of people download all sorts of media all the time, in the US specifically, including most probably academic textbooks)... and that's why I asked.

Comment: @aeismail: The page you linked to claims Fair Use is limited to criticism and commentary. So, it doesn't actually address the issue of use for scholarship at all ... oh, wait, it's worse! The guide claims that "a fair use is any copying of copyrighted material done for a limited and “transformative” purpose" - but scholarship does not have any inherent transformative aspect. So, I'd say that text misrepresents the law in this respect.

Comment: @einpoklum in the US it IS well established, there have been many rulings. Lots of people downloading media illegally does not make it legal, they are not doing it under any kind of fair use exemption, there are just too many to practically chase. It is an area that law is having trouble dealing with and may need to change, but at present what the law IS is very clear.

Comment: @einpoklum also this is NOT legal in Isreal. As party to the Berne convention copyright applies there too. In fact Isreal's copyright system is modelled on the US one and it's definition of fair use is very similar.

Comment: @JamesRyan: It is legal in Israel; could you indicate where/how the Berne convention forbids what I've described in the question?

Comment: @einpoklum Israel changed it's copyright law in 2007 from British style to US and the implications of this are widely analysed. So while you say is it legal I am afraid reality is that you are simply ignorant of the law.

Comment: @JamesRyan: The new law kept in effect the [personal use article of the 1924 copyright ordinance](http://www.nevo.co.il/law_html/law01/130_003.htm) (article 3-gimel). Your insistence on misrepresenting Israeli law makes me doubt your claims about what's "well-established" in US law even more.

Comment: @einpoklum that is absolutely not the case. Fair use was limited to study, that does not mean it exempts all study (eg some cars are green does not imply that all cars are green) http://www.tglaw.co.il/en/content.php?id=27

Comment: @JamesRyan: You, can ignore the law all you like, it's written, black on white: "It shall not be a violation of the rights of creators and performs to imprint or to copy a creation onto a tape for private and home use without commercial purposes." The source you linked to is a legal opinion column by a law office which needs to attract foreign clients, to represent in trying to sue for copyright infringement. So, my doubts regarding your claims about US law again deepen.

Comment: @einpoklum again YOU are misinterpreting.  That clause is for people to make backups of media that they already have in their possesion it does NOT allow other people to freely distribute it to you

Comment: @einpoklum if you have a lot of confusion about your own laws then it will be hard for you to understand the laws of other regions. Do you have a legal advisor at your institute that you could discuss this topic with, maybe they can clear up some of your misconceptions?

Comment: @JamesRyan: That clause is crystal clear, and your interpretation is baseless - not to mention the fact that you've switched from your previous factually incorrect claim to a new one. There's no "confusion". By the way, how come you're so (baselessly) confident about Israeli law? Do you read Hebrew?

Comment: @einpoklum I have an Israeli aquaitance, he has confirmed that you are misinterpreting. If you are refusing to accept that then there is no point in continuing this conversation. I know 100% that you are wrong and I suggested the local advisor because you might be able to accept it easier from a source that you trust

Comment: @JamesRyan: With all due respect - we've established your acquaintance is feeding you claims which contradict the letter of the law. Let him argue here himself if he (or she) is so inclinded. Or rather, please don't, since the question is about US law.

Comment: @einpoklum you haven't established anything of the sort and if you arn't prepared to listen to what the answer IS when reality doesn't match your preconceived misconception then what was the point in asking at all?  Just continue making up what you like.

Comment: @JamesRyan: You're not helping me get an answer to my question, you're trying to promote your anti-copying agenda. Please, just stop.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't have any agenda, I am a consumer and if anything in support of free-er laws, you however are simply refusing to acknowledge reality

Comment: @einpoklum: The reality is that the law is heavily biased against free distribution of copyrighted materials. As an example of this, consider the [Petrucci Music Library](http://www.imslp.org), which, as a result of copyright law, is unable to offer scores from any composers _alive_ after 1945 unless they've been specifically released into the public domain. It is a major problem, but the fact remains that the law is not on the side of allowing what you suggest.

Comment: @JamesRyan This is a useless argument as einpoklum has no intention of listening to reason and is basically a troll. In the post that he references, I provided an example of Israeli case law. ff524 chose to delete those comments, but never the less, even presented with Israeli case law, they rejected it and claimed they were still correct. http://www.iipa.com/rbc/2012/2012SPEC301ISRAEL.PDF "In June 2011, in the case of Hebrew University of Jerusalem vs. Yaakov Cohen, the Supreme Court of Israel clarified the doctrine of contributory copyright infringement under Israeli law..."

Comment: "... This case sets an important legal principle under which those who, while not directly infringing, can nevertheless be held contributorily liable for copyright infringement of others."

Comment: @JamesRyan, I also pointed out that Israeli is a party to most of the major International Copyright treaties of the latter half of the 20th Century, http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ38a.pdf including the 1995 WTO agreement that 160 nations are party to. "World Trade Organization (WTO), established ... The Agreement on Trade-Related Aspects of Intellectual Property Rights (TRIPS) is one of the WTO agreements. It includes substantive obligations for the protection of copyright and other intellectual property rights as well as their enforcement."

Answer (score -1):

It's my understanding is that "fair use" is about the **reproduction** of copyrighted materials.

I don't believe it has anything to do with how you **obtained** those materials.

If you stole the same textbook from Barnes & Noble, would you claim fair use?

It is true that the RIAA and others are suing on copyright grounds & not for plain theft.

How that works exactly, I'm not sure. [You can read more about it on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_aspects_of_file_sharing#Copyright_law).

This excerpt is relevant to your question:

> Where a defendant has admitted downloading and copying song files from
>   other users in the P2P network without permission of the copyright
>   holders, she cannot claim that such copying is a "fair use".

Comment: The analogy to stealing from Barnes & Noble is a false analogy that is not related to the issue at hand. If you steal from a bookstore, you are stealing from the retailer (who is not the copyright holder), and you are not making a new copy of the book, nor violating any other of the copyright holder's exclusive rights. Downloading a book in PDF form, in contrast, does not involve stealing from a retailer and *does* involve making a (digital) copy of the book, which is an exclusive right granted to the copyright holder. (It's similar to making a photocopy of an entire book from the library.)

Comment: The first two sentences would be worth upvoting. Unfortunately, the rest seems rather confused since the question is whether somebody could be sued for breach of copyright (legitimately) and not whether s/he could be prosecuted for theft. But, it *is* true that the idea of 'fair use' applies to use of copyrighted materials and not to their acquisition, as I understand it. (Or, at least, it should apply to use. But what it actually permits in practice is very little.)

Comment: I've read this "answer" five times now and I don't see an actual answer in it.