# Is it legal to download textbooks from academia.edu?

Tags: united-states, books, online-resource, law

There is a website called academia.edu. It seems like they have papers on various topics - but my question is about their textbooks. It is possible to download certain college textbooks for free through their site. [This](https://www.academia.edu/34515403/Smith_-_Calculus_Early_Transcendentals_Functions_4th_c2012_txtbk) is a link to a calculus textbook you can download through the site.

My question is: Is it legal to download textbooks from academia.edu (in the United States)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academia.edu

Comment: The legality would depend upon your specific jurisdiction. There are also several similar questions on this site. assuming you're in the US, your question is a duplicate https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54029/is-it-legal-in-the-us-for-a-student-to-download-a-copy-of-a-textbook-to-study

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal in the US for a student to download a copy of a textbook, to study?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54029/is-it-legal-in-the-us-for-a-student-to-download-a-copy-of-a-textbook-to-study)

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: @RichardErickson: That's a different case. academia.edu is not sci-hub or library genesis, it's more "respectable" and public

Comment: @einpoklum Not really. The legality of downloading a textbook doesn't matter where you download it per say. The exception could be website specific, (e.g., publisher, authors, or funding agencies might allow legal download from their webpage). However, even some author supplied downloads can be illegal if their publishing licence does not allow it. The overlap (or lack of overlap) of ethics and legality would be a different question :)

Comment: @RichardErickson: See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who downloaded a textbook from there could make the argument that they had good-faith belief that the content on the website is available for public use, and was not aware of any legislation barring them from such download.

Thus, even if somewhere in the world it is illegal (which I doubt), the person downloading the book is extremely unlikely to get prosecuted or sued, and were they to be prosecuted - extremely unlikely of being convicted.

This, as opposed to textbooks you somehow got (without being able to make any assumptions about the source of the file.

Comment: So downloading from academia.edu would be legal in the USA

Comment: @Burt: I didn't say that. It still depends on what you download and how it got online.